# Why does readdir only read 32K of directory entries at a time?

Tags: linux, filesystems, buffer

> `readdir()` only reads 32K of directory entries at a time.

Why does it read only 32K entries in one shot? Is it dependent on buffer or any other parameters?

Can I change that value so that I can read as many directory entries as I want?

Comment: "Why it reads only 32K entries?" sounds like you are going to explain why that is the case, but there rest of the paragraph doesn't do that. Did you mean "Why does it read only 32K entries?" (to which the answer probably is: efficiency).

Comment: What I want to ask is why 32K? Whether it is fixed or it depends on system parameters such as buffer size.

Comment: If you want to ask that, please use the normal question form "Why does it read only 32K entries". It is maybe because English is not my native language, but your phrasing is incomprehensible (at least to me).

Comment: I understood the question nevertheless, but motivations aren't clear. Though I guess that gwillie's answer addresses your question correctly.

Comment: Are you asking about readdir the library routine, or readdir the old system call?

Comment: readdir syscall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum number of directories is file system dependent:

- ext2: 32768
- ext3: 31998
- ext4: 65000. use `dir_nlink` flag to increase this number

It's only since 2006 when `ext4` was ratified that max directory limits were increased above 32000 mark, so there would be no point for `readdir()` to read more than that.

If you have more than 32000 subdirectories, I would consider learning about performance degradation due to large amount of subdirectoies

Comment: Is that the maximum number of subdirectories per directory? My man page for `ext4` has `dir_nlink` described as "allows more than 65000 subdirectories per directory", which hints at that. I don't think that's not the same as the max number of _files_ per directory, and `readdir()` reads files too. Also, the phrase is "32K _of_ directory entries", not "32K directory entries", so if that means the buffer size in bytes, the actual number of entries read would be lower.

Answer (score 1):

glibc's `opendir()` function calculates the allocation for `readdir()` as `MIN(MAX(statp->st_blksize, 32KB), 1MB)`.  The filesystem can recommend an I/O block size via `st_blksize`. On `ext4` it is:

```
$ stat -c '%o' .
4096
```

So, `readdir()` will use a 32KB buffer (because this is larger than 4KB).

I don't know of a way of configuring `st_blksize` on `ext4` (or other filesystems).